# Join Textiew Value and voice recognition

Tags: android, join, textview, voice-recognition

I am using below code to transfer voice recording into a `TextView` called `txtSpeechInput`. However, if there is a value in the `TextView` already I would like the data to Join with it rather than type over

Anyone able to help?

```
switch (requestCode) {
  case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
       ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
       txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
    }
  }
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To append the new data to the existing text in the text view you can do the following after getting the result array:

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(txtSpeechInput.getText().toString());

sb.append(result.get(0));

txtSpeechInput.setText(sb.toString());

Comment: Thanks so much , is there a way to put a "return " to a new line or a ; between the 2 strings ?

Comment: You can append whatever you like in between them with an additional .append() method call.  So after initializing the string builder you could do sb.append("\r\n").append(result.get(0)); for a new line for example.